# Saving Facebooks signed_request?

Tags: php, facebook

**The situation**
I am playing around with the new Facebook iFrame tabs on pages. I am using the signed_request to get some facts about the app, the page and the user.

**To challenge**
Facebook provides the signed_request params via $_REQUEST only on the first call of the iframe. The problem is to access the parms a second time e.g. for an ajax request.

**This is how i did it**
I extended the PHP SDK like this to store the signed_request in a cookie.

```
/**
 * The name of the Cookie that contains the session.
 * @return String the cookie name
 */
protected function getSessionSignedRequestCookieName() {
    return 'fbs_sr_' . $this->getAppId();
}

/**
 * Saves the signed_request as a browser coookie
 * @return void;
 */
protected function saveSignedRequestAsCookie($signedRequest) {
    $cookieName = $this->getSessionSignedRequestCookieName();

    setcookie($cookieName, serialize($signedRequest));
}

/**
 * Returns the SigndRequest from $_COOKIE
 * @return array
 */
public function getSignedRequestFromCookie() {
    $cookieName = $this->getSessionSignedRequestCookieName();

    if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookieName])) {
        $this->signedRequest = $_COOKIE[$cookieName];
        return unserialize($this->signedRequest);
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the data from a signed_request token provided by $_REQUEST or $_SESSION
 * @return array The decoede signed Request
 */
public function getSignedRequest() {
    $signedRequest = parent::getSignedRequest();

    if($signedRequest != NULL) {
        $this->saveSignedRequestAsCookie($signedRequest);
        return $signedRequest;
    } else {
        return $this->getSignedRequestFromCookie();
    }
}
```

*What to you think**
I that a good idea or a bad workaround? Any suggestions/ improvements?

Comment: Hi,

I like your piece of code. I used it to get the signed request.

But I get this error:

Fatal error: Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent in

Any idea why?

Thanks

Dibs

Comment: You need to extend the official facebook php sdk.

Comment: Do you think sessions would work in the same way? Why not to use them, why to use cookies?

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution worked for me with one little flaw: unserialize returned an empty object, so  I saved the base64 encoded json format of the signed request (what Facebook sends to the canvas app)